# How to write key with tuple values in CSV using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I want to write a specific key with tuple values in a CSV file using Python. I cannot currently use numby or any other python external library. I am using "zip" to achieve this but only the first value associated with the key is getting directed, whereas, I want to print all the values in the tuple.
A sample dictionary and code are provided below:

```
data = {
    "Pakistan": (0.57, 0.05, 0.79),
    "India": (0.47, 0.12, 0.54),
    "Bangladesh": (0.49, 0.17, 0.81)
    }
con_name = input("Write up to three comma-separated countries for which you want to extract data: ")
count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', con_name))
if count == 1:
    con_check1 = con_name.split()[0]
    if con_check1.lower() in map(str.lower, data.keys()):
        con_check1 = con_check1.capitalize()
        x = list(data.keys()).index(con_check1)
        y = [key for key in data.keys()][x]
        csv_columns = ['Country Name','1997','1998','1999']
        with open('Emissions_subset.csv','w') as out:
            csv_out=csv.writer(out)
            csv_out.writerow(csv_columns) 
            z = [y]
            csv_out.writerows(zip(z, data[con_check1]))
```

The current output in the CSV file:

```
Country Name, 1997, 1998, 1999
Pakistan      0.57
```

The desired output:

```
Country Name, 1997, 1998, 1999
Pakistan      0.57, 0.05, 0.79
```

Can you please help me with this issue? I have been asking some questions lately and nobody is answering me. I am really stuck here and only ask a question after I am exhausted of trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   [In]    kv_list = [[key,*val] for key, val in data.items()]
   [In]   print(kv_list)
   [Out]  [['Pakistan', 0.57, 0.05, 0.79], ['India', 0.47, 0.12, 0.54], ['Bangladesh', 0.49, 0.17, 0.81]]
```

Then just use `csv_out.writerows(kv_list)`.